# I want to send data from Modbus TCP to Modbus RTU in Python 3

Tags: python

Values from ModSim: [258]
Error writing to ModScan register 0: No communication with the instrument (no answer)
Im getting this error

I wrote the code in python but its giving me error I can see my value in modscan but its not going to the right register my modsim(TCP) is sending data in decimal format but the in RTU it should out in integer format

Comment: Without seeing your code, there is little we can do.  What device are you sending to?

Comment: I'm sending it to modscan in my laptop

Comment: I'm running modsim in a one laptop and modscan on another  laptop made some physical connection I'm getting my data on 40003 it should be seen on 40001 in modscan